# How to mark loser as winner in p2p replication conflict resolution

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

We have sql server 2008 databases in 2 different regions that are `p2p replicated`.

Now we can see there are some unresolved conflicts - most of them update/delete conflicts. The way our system is designed allows us to safely assume delete commands should be 'winners' against update commands. But most of the `delete` commands are losers.

So I'm wondering is there any way to make `losers`(`delete` commands) as new `winners`.
I came across this [article](https://repltalk.com/2011/04/19/clearing-resolved-merge-replication-conflicts/). There is a way to mark `looser` as `new winner` but article applies to `merge replication` and probably that's the reason I don't see respective buttons to mark `losers` as `new winner` for our `p2p replication`.

So my question is - Is there any way to mark `losers` as `new winners` in `p2p replication`?

Comment: @Verace after your edit article link is broken. Could you please fix it.

Comment: Corrected - my apologies. Will test link changes in future.